# How to update two columns in IF statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

```
TableA (columnA, columnB,columnC)
```

and I have this T-SQL statement:

```
ALTER TRIGGER TableB ON TableA  
AFTER UPDATE  
AS             
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF UPDATE(columnA)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE TableA
        SET ColumnX= GETDATE()      
        FROM ( ---- ---)
        WHERE --- = ---
    END
END
```

My concern is how can I make it to two or more columns in the `IF UPDATE()` statement. Comma (`,`) is not working.

Comment: It's basically like this `IF (UPDATE(Column1) OR UPDATE(Column2)) BEGIN ... END`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (update(columnA) or update(columnB))...
```